# Change backgrond color with clicked radio only pure JS please

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I just asked the same question few moments ago with jQuery before to know that the client don't want jQuery on his project.

So I wish to change the background color of a block when a radio button, which is inner the block, is clicked. Only with pure Javascript please.

Here is the code which I still don't know why it don't work.

```html
<style>
  .radio-active {
    background-color: $primaryColor;
    color: $whiteColor;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="changeColor()">
    <label class="radio-label" for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById('label').className += "radio-active";
    console.log('hiiiiiiiii');
  }

  function init() {
    document.getElementById("rad").onclick = changeColor;
  }

  window.onload = init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your `init` function is running before the elements have been rendered, because you are calling the function instead of just assigning it to be the callback for `window.onload`.

So `window.onload = init();` should become `window.onload = init;`

**Edit**: It could also be that your CSS is failing (silently) because the color variables (like `$primaryColor`) aren't declared anywhere. Try with some regular colors like `red`, `blue`.

And the styles may not be visible for other reasons. Try with a more extreme style rule, like `display: none;`.

Also, like the [kukkuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6231153/kukkuz) said,  the adding of the class (`className += "radio-active"`) should be done just with `=`  not`+=`, or using their method (if you want to toggle back and forth).

Comment: Any errors in the console? Might be problems with the syntax or something like that.

Comment: I mean the hiiiiiii message

Comment: The message works for me if I use ordinary colors in the style, instead of color variables. I updated the answer with this info. Try changing the style to something more fool proof as well. I tried with display: none;   It worked.

Comment: Variable work perfectly on sass and nothing is missing. But I tried with extreme style rule and nothing change. I tired also with just "=" and with classList.toggle and still nothing.

Comment: Then I would say the problem lies outside of the code you have so far provided. Because if you copy the code in your question into jsfiddle or a similar web editor, then it works (with the adjustments I've mentioned). https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/xLwqgnLy/

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! Thank you a lot. I had conflict with an existing plugin. Really thank you 5* :)

Comment: No problem! Good that you found the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You are *appending* to the `class` attribute and after you click two times it becomes:

```
radio-activeradio-active
```

Instead you can *toggle* the `classList` - see demo below:

Note that I'm using a `checkbox` here as its more suited to the task here.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('label').classList.toggle("radio-active");
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("rad").onclick = changeColor;
}

window.onload = init();
```

```css
.radio-active {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="checkbox" name="rad" onclick="changeColor()">
    <label class="radio-label" for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The javascript is all here, no class or id conflict for sure. the html and css is too long I'm not sure I can post it

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this:

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('label').className += "radio-active";
}
```

```css
.radio-active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="changeColor()">
    <label class="radio-label" for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you just want to use JS and no CSS at all, you can set a `cssString` like so:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var cssString = 'background-color: black; color: white;'
  document.getElementById("label").style.cssText = cssString;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="changeColor()">
    <label class="radio-label" for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  .radio-active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li id="my_label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="changeColor()">
    <label class="radio-label" for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  var changeColor = function() {
     document.getElementById("my_label").classList.add("radio-active");
  }

</script>
```